# Animate CSS Keyframes from JS

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations, keyframe

i want to trigger a animation based on css keyframes from javascript.
After reading through some answers on stackoverflow i tried using the jquery addClass function (click on the blue shape to start the animation):
https://codepen.io/valentin-wei/pen/KKMRrYK

```
  With this approach i can only animate it once.
```

Is there a way to consistantly animate this shape back and forth by using javascript?

Answer (score 0):

The solution you are looking for is either `javascript` OR wise use of `css-keyframes`:

In your codepen sample `replace everything inside you css with this code`:

```
test {
  background-color: blue;
  width:346px;
  height:213px;
    clip-path:  polygon(323.19px 0.00px, 0.00px 186.65px, 0.00px 213.00px, 346.00px 13.17px, 323.19px 0.00px);
}

.animate { 
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-name: animtest;
  animation-delay: 0;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: forward;
}
.reverseanimate { 
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-name: animtest;
  animation-delay: 0;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: reverse;
}

@keyframes animtest {
  0% {
    clip-path: polygon(323.19px 0.00px, 0.00px 186.65px, 0.00px 213.00px, 346.00px 13.17px, 323.19px 0.00px)
  }
  100% {
    clip-path: polygon(0.00px 168.65px, 0.00px 229.00px, 345.00px 30.17px, 292.64px 0.00px, 0.00px 168.65px)
  }
}
```

then, `replace everything inside you js with this code`:

```
let target = document.getElementById('test');
 setInterval(function(){  
 if ($(target).hasClass("animate")) {
    $(target).removeClass("animate");
    $(target).addClass("reverseanimate");
  }
  else {
    $(target).addClass("animate");
    $(target).removeClass("reverseanimate");
  }
 }, 3000);
```

NOTE: I couldn't make an account in codepen for some reason

Comment: Thanks for your answer but unfortunately this solution doesnt work for me. The "click" event was just an example. I need to be able to trigger the animation and its reverse counterpart completely from javascript

Comment: I edited my answer also, I used jQuery(not vanilla js) this time using setIntervals(), you can also replace it as a fully fledge function instead of a method. cant really tell what answer your hoping for

Comment: Thats for your edit. Its almost what im looking for. However I dont want it to animate constantly. It should just animate the animation or reverseanimation (depending on the animation state) one Time only on call. With your solution the animation never stops for example if i remove the interval (probably because of the infinite animation-iteration-count). I tried to mess around with your suggestion changing up some parameters or putting it into a click event but i couldnt get the result i wanted. I hope this clarifies my question.

Answer (score 0):

After some further research i was able to fix this problem.

Instead of using the css animation property i use a transition now:

```
.animate { 
   transition: clip-path 3s;
   clip-path: polygon(0.00px 168.65px, 0.00px 229.00px, 345.00px 30.17px, 292.64px 0.00px, 0.00px 168.65px)

}
.reverseanimate { 
   transition: clip-path 3s;
   clip-path: polygon(323.19px 0.00px, 0.00px 186.65px, 0.00px 213.00px, 346.00px 13.17px, 323.19px 0.00px)
}
```

I've also updated my codepen to provide a working example: https://codepen.io/valentin-wei/pen/KKMRrYK